# Select list not getting populated when css is added

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code snippet. When I remove the section and div tags, the list gets populated otherwise it doesn't. Why is this happening? CSS shouldn't effect the php code.

```
        <section name="s1" class="container">
       <div class="dropdown">
  <p> <h5 style="color:#CCC"> Select a quiz to analyze</h5></p>
    <select name="one" class="dropdown-select">
      <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
     echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
   ?>
     </select>
   </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Please check in both the classes are you having any display:none; property ?

Comment: Check your CSS, and maybe some JS? Are you using any JS script to transform your `select`?